# Error code expected a')' occurring on logical operators

Tags: c++, logical-operators

This error code just appeared all of a sudden and this never happened before. It has a red under line on all of the logical operators like (and, or) and it shows the error expected a')' but the code is running well. Does somebody know why this is happening?

Here's the sample code

```
    while (item_list[index].title != item and index != last + 1) //error occurs here underlines red at the and operator
    {
        ++index;
    }
    if (index != last + 1)
    {
        cout << "Item is found at row " << index + 1 << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Item is not found in the table"
             << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Which IDE would be good to know

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste the compilation error. 2) "_It has a red under line_" So is it an intellisense error, or a compilation error? 3) "_the code is running well_" If the code didn't compile - it wouldn't run.

Comment: IDEs can get confused sometimes, I could even imagine that yours does not know `and` (its not that common). What counts is what your compiler does to the code

Comment: Sounds like your IDE doesn't like `and` and is expecting `&&`, whilst the compiler you're using is fine with it.

Comment: visual studio code is the IDE

Comment: VSCode is just an editor, all red lines come from some plugin.

Comment: Irrespective of the cause of the problem I would recommend `&&` instead of `and`. It's the usual thing to do.

Comment: ok well i'll do that instead

Comment: @john IMHO `and` makes the code more readable but it's opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
while (item_list[index].title != item and index != last + 1)
```

change the and to &&, there is no operator called and in C++ only && no and....